# What are the drawbacks of Lamport's happens-before algorithm?

Tags: operating-system

I have been reading about Lamport's happens-before technique to detect race conditions in multi-threaded programs. I do not understand its drawbacks correctly. Can someone please explain ? I have been reading the paper - Erasor - A dynamic race detector for multi-threaded programs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Eraser](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.175.3886) lists two drawbacks of detectors based on happens-before:

1. They are slow.  This is less true these days than when Eraser was published.  Look at [FastTrack](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/11/100634-fasttrack-efficient-and-precise-dynamic-race-detection/fulltext).
2. Their results depend on the actual order of synchronization operations in a particular execution.  That is, the bug must actually exhibit itself to be detected.  This is more a fundamental property of happens-before.

I can't think of any other drawbacks offhand.